# How do I have to match the format between time data ' 01/27/1998' to '%d/%m/%y'?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I just tried to display my birthday(dd/mm/yyyy).
And then, I got "ValueError" 
which is like "time data %r does not match format %r" % and
"time data ' 01/27/1998' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'"

Here is my code

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

birthday = input('When is your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy)?')

birthday_date = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%d/%m/%y")

print('Birthday : ' + str(birthday_date))

one_day = timedelta(days=1)
birthday_eve = birthday_date - one_day
print('Day before birthday : ' + str(birthday_eve))
```

This is the detail of error

```
When is your birthday (dd/mm/yyyy)? 01/27/1998
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "010-input_date.py", line 5, in <module>
    birthday_date = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%d/%m/%y")
  File 
"C:\Users\Kohei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", 
line 568,
in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File 
"C:\Users\Kohei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\_strptime.py", 
line 349,
in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data ' 01/27/1998' does not match format '%d/%m/%y'
```

Answer (score 6):

It has to be, `'%d/%m/%Y'`, so replace the following line:

```
birthday_date = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%d/%m/%y")
```

With:

```
birthday_date = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

From your traceback it looks like you have a little bit of whitespace there. The golden rule is: always clean user input.

```
birthday_date = datetime.strptime(birthday.strip(), "%d/%m/%y")
```

Remove the whitespace and all is well.

Also `%y` only matches 2 digits. If you want to match 4 it's `%Y`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you specify `dd/mm/yyyy`, but you fed in `01/27/1998` which is `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
birthday_date = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%m/%d/%Y")  # fixed
```

Also note that `%Y` matches a 4-digit year while `%y` only matches the last 2 digits. ([Reference link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes))